# kubernetes: how to link secret tls crt/key with files or configMap?

Tags: kubernetes

Is there a way to link secret tls crt/key with files?

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: hello-app-tls
  namespace: dev
type: kubernetes.io/tls
data:
  tls.crt: <crt_filePath>
  tls.key: <key_filePath>
```

Or reference values from a ConfigMap like:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: hello-app-tls
  namespace: dev
type: kubernetes.io/tls
data:
  tls.crt:
    valueFrom:
       configMapKeyRef:
         name: configmap_tls
         key: crt
  tls.key:
    valueFrom:
       configMapKeyRef:
         name: configmap_tls
         key: key
```

Error:

```
Secret in version "v1" cannot be handled as a Secret: json: cannot unmarshal object into Go struct field Secret.data of type []uint8
```

Comment: Did you have time to check my answer? It helped you to solve your issue? If not, I am happy to assist further.

Answer (score 0):

That cryptic error about unmarshalling string to a map of string means that the module was unable to resolve the content of values parameter to the contents of the actual file. Which caused the issue.

In your secret you can't give data directly. You have to encode your data in base64 format.

As mentioned in the github [link](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/5550#issuecomment-1143160308) by @ MadEngineX, try running the below command at data field:

```
tls.crt: {{ .Files.Get "api-gateway/google/files/tls.crt" | b64enc | quote  }}
```

Or

```
tls.crt: {{ .Files.Get "api-gateway/google/files/tls.crt" | toString | b64enc | quote   }}
```

Example-

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: hello-app-tls
  namespace: dev
type: kubernetes.io/tls
data:
  tls.crt: {{ .Files.Get "api-gateway/google/files/tls.crt" | b64enc | quote  }}
```

Comment: api-gateway/google/files/tls.crt: where is it located? thanks.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Kindly refer to the Github link mentioned above for clear understanding.

Comment: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: invalid map key: map[interface {}]interface {}{".Files.Get \"ssl/cert.pem\" | b64enc | quote":interface {}(nil)}

Comment: Refer to this Github [link](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/2004). Let me know if this helps.